# PHP htaccces url rewrite challenge

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

as far as I'm not experienced this challenge is too much for me. I need to rewrite ugly and complicated urls to clean.

From:

```
domain.com/index.php?job=wiad&idg=3&id=42&x=20&n_id=8
```

to smth like this:

```
domain.com/read/part1/article8
```

It's pretty old app and **IDG, ID, ID** - are in table1 in DB and **N_ID** is in table2 in DB. I got a names related to these Id's:

```
$requesturi = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$urlinitial = explode("?",$requesturi); 
parse_str(html_entity_decode($requesturi), $get_array);
foreach($get_array as $key => $value) {$key = $value;}
$sql = "SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE idg=$idg and id=$id and x=$x";
$sql2 = "SELECT title FROM table2 WHERE n_id=$n_id";
```

Finally I've got two variables with current name of section and article: **$page_name** and **$art_name.**

Part **index.php?job=wiad** is a changeable pattern and depends on role: **job=wiad** means show article and normal view is **index_php?idg**...I think I should make a kind of **RewriteRule** and mix it with another .php settings file.

Answer (score 0):

```html
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)$ index.php?job=wiad&idg=$1&id=$2&x=$3&n_id=$4 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thx @spickywolf but that's not the answer :/ To be honest nothing has changed when I try to open article, there is old & ugly url. Is it possible to rewrite it with some kind of pattern (sorry for obvious mistakes)... f.ex: ^read.php/$page_name/$article_name/$  and make there - in read.php file -  parse_str with url?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?job=$1&idg=$2&id=$3&x=$4&n_id=$5 [L]

Answer (score 0):

### **Or you can use this**

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ /index.php?job=$1&idg=$2&id=$3&x=$4&n_id=$5 [L]

Comment: I did - it gave me an output like: domain.com/wiad/3/42/20/8.html - good, but not enough. I'd like to use the relation between id's and name of column and constuct url with name insead of numbers. Thx for your effort!

Comment: this can help you link : http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php